# SQL Server connection problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 running on a remote server.

It works fine for my application, how ever if I change the connection string in `web.config` file and redirect it to another SQL Server, then I get an error "could not connect to remote server".

I have added the detail of the error type, i get those error.Using sqlserver object explorer i can connect to the server and see the database. but using the same username and password in my webconfiguration file i cannot connect and got the above mentioned error.

I get also this error offending URL. What could be the possible way to figure out?
 error is offending url and unknown server authentication

```
 http://myweb.com/login
Source: System.Web
Message: Unable to connect to SQL Server session database.
Stack trace: at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.ThrowSqlConnectionException(SqlConnection conn, Exception e)
at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SqlStateConnection..ctor(SqlPartitionInfo sqlPartitionInfo)
at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetConnection(String id, Boolean& usePooling)
at System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: any errors? excptions? can you ping the server? can you telnet [server] 1433?

Comment: yes server is up and the error is offending url and unknown server authentication

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to help, but I can take some stabs in the dark. See if any of these links help : http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/09/15/policy-based-management-and-the-unknown-loginmode.aspx http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2010/09/15/watch-out-for-old-stuff.aspx http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326985

Comment: Check if: 1. Using the same user and password you can connect to both servers. 2. Check SQL Server Network Configuration that the protocols are enabled for your servers. 3. If you can, give more info about your problem

Comment: @Radu Caprescu, I have added the detail of the error type, i get those error.Using sqlserver object explorer i can connect to the server and see the database. but using the same username and password in my webconfiguration file i cannot connect and got the above mentioned error.

Comment: @rlb.use: I have added the detail of the error type, i get those error.Using sqlserver object explorer i can connect to the server and see the database. but using the same username and password in my webconfiguration file i cannot connect and got the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you can check:

1. Check that the SQL Server on the romete machine is running
2. Check if there is a firewall on the remote machine that is blocking the 1433 TCP port and the 1434 UDP port
3. Check if TCP/IP remote connection are enabled inside SQL connection protocls
4. Set explicitly the TCP port 1433 foreach ip address on the TCP/IP on the SQL network configuration
5. Check if sql server browser is running on the remote machine

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added the detail of the error type, i get those error.Using sqlserver object explorer i can connect to the server and see the database. but using the same username and password in my webconfiguration file i cannot connect and got the above mentioned error.

Comment: Could you show me the connectionStrings section of you web.config file?